# createsite event handler in sharepoint online

Tags: event-handlers, site-template, sharepoint-online, web

I am writing an event handler that will create a new site whenever the new item is added to the list. My issue is it creates a new site everytime but it does and does not (randomly) execute the code following the Webs.Add(..). It looks like creating a new site somehow explodes without being caught by try catch.

This issue is on a Sharepoint Online environment (so impossible to debug) but works perfectly fine on a sandbox solution(on the developer machine VM).We are using team site templates.

I initially suspected to be some kind of threading related issue so my even handler is singlton, but that didnt help.

Comment: Could this be a permissions issue? Does the user adding the item have permission to create a site?

Comment: Can you post your code here? I really think it might be something with the code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 30 second execution cutoff in SharePoint Online (not sure about wave 15 yet). Have a look at your stopwatch, at the 30s mark the code will die without throwing an error. It probably works as a sandbox solution on your dev machine because it is faster.. Yes I have experienced this before.